# Is there a minimum altitude at which FAA drone rules apply?

Tags: faa, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I know the rules for maximum altitude for a drone is 400ft (in general) but is there a minimum height at which the rules are applied?  For example is a drone flying 12 inches off the ground subject to the same rules as one flying at 400ft?

Answer (score 6):

> I know the rules for maximum altitude for a drone is 400ft (in
> general) but is there a minimum height at which the rules are applied?

No.

> For example is a drone flying 12 inches off the ground subject to the
> same rules as one flying at 400ft?

Yes.

See--

[Guide to drone regulations](https://jrupprechtlaw.com/faa-part-107/)

[CFR Part 107](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-107)

[49 U.S. Code § 44809 - Exception for limited recreational operations of unmanned aircraft](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/49/44809)